# Count number occurrences of a String in a table and report it in a new column

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, rdbms

Input

```
Name
A
A
B
B
B
B
C
B
C
A
D
```

Required Output

```
Name    Occurance
A   1
A   2
B   1
B   2
B   3
B   4
C   1
B   5
C   2
A   3
D   1
```

Please Note - I have more than 100000 unique entries in the name column and hence I cannot hardcode name in the code

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected result shows (for example) that A occurs 3 times and gets numbered 1, 2, 3 even though they don't all occur together. A single row_number() will suffice: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0cd0c/1)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (ID int identity(1,1) primary key, [Name] varchar(1));   
INSERT INTO Table1 ([Name])
VALUES     ('A'),('A'),('B'),('B'),('B'),('B'),('C'),('B'),('C'),('A'),('D');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
       name
     , row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as Occurance
from table1
order by id
```

As tables are considered unordered sets, to reproduce the sequence shown in the expected result there would have to be some other column(s) for that. I have assumed an identity column ID for that.

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0cd0c/1/0)**:

```
| name | Occurance |
|------|-----------|
|    A |         1 |
|    A |         2 |
|    B |         1 |
|    B |         2 |
|    B |         3 |
|    B |         4 |
|    C |         1 |
|    B |         5 |
|    C |         2 |
|    A |         3 |
|    D |         1 |
```

If you aren't familiar with these, I recommend you do become so as they are extremely handy:

1. [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)
2. [SELECT - OVER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql)

Comment: Thank you very much, easy and perfect answer plus the reference topics that you gave are truly handy.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Ordering is provided only by columns that specify the ordering.

Assuming you have an ordering -- such as an identity `id` column -- you can use the difference of row numbers approach:

```
select name, count(*)
from (select name,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum_n
      from t
     ) t
group by name, (seqnum - seqnum_n);
```

To understand why this works, you have to stare at the results of the subquery until you "get" why the difference defines adjacent values.